# Using setInterval in function with internal call (js)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, ecmascript-6

I have such code here. I want to display result with time interval in a few seconds. But it doesn't work.

```
const moveCranes = setInterval(function(plate, slot_a, slot_b, slot_c) {
    if (plate > 0) {
        moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_a, slot_c, slot_b);
        port_a.innerHTML = "Move plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "<br />";
    moveCranes(plate - 1,slot_b, slot_a, slot_c);
    }
}, 2000);
moveCranes(input.value,"slot_a","slot_b","slot_c");
```

Can you explain what do I wrong and why doesn't the setInterval doesn't work?

Comment: `moveCranes` is not a function; it's the ID returned by `setInterval()`.

Comment: @SLaks  How to make the right syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
function moveCranes(plate, slot_a, slot_b, slot_c) { /*
^^^^^^^^ */
    setInterval(function() {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^ this inner function takes no parameters
        if (plate > 0) {
            moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_a, slot_c, slot_b);
            port_a.innerHTML = "Move plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "<br />";
            moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_b, slot_a, slot_c);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

And since you are recursively calling the function again, you probably wanted to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: thanks, what os better to use in this case: setInterval or SetTimeout?

Comment: Well I don't know what "*this case*" is - what should the code do?

Comment: I do an application about cranes. And I have 3 div (start, middle and final place). It's like Tower of Hanoi. In each div I want to see what happens there. To make the process visual slowly I set time interval

Comment: Ah ok. First I'd suggest to change `innerHTML = …` to `innerHTML += …` so that you can better see what happens.

Comment: Yes you will definitely want `setTimeout`, as each invocation of `moveCranes` should only run the inner function once (not repeatedly). But there's another problem: you are calling `moveCranes(pate - 1, …)` twice, right after each other. Both of them schedule something to happen after 2s, and so after 2s *both* callbacks will run at the same time. To make them work sequentially, you will need to use callbacks.

Comment: U are right. It repeats steps 2 times. Can you haw can I change the code to avoid this?

Comment: Have learned about callbacks yet? You will need to give the `moveCranes` an additional parameter, a function that it should call after all its animations are done. Then for your recursive calls, pass a function to the first that does the output and then calls the second, and to this second call pass a function that does something at the end of the task.

Comment: Best find some tutorial about asynchronous callbacks in JavaScript, and try to implement what I described. You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) then if you're struggling.